# Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I got this error "Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    at syntaxError" while using ng-lazyload-image for lazy load images.

my code AppModule.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LazyLoadImageModule ,intersectionObserverPreset } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,LazyLoadImageModule.forRoot({
      preset: intersectionObserverPreset
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export interface Image {
  defaultImage: string;
  image: string;
}
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  images: Image[] = [];

  // defaultImage = 'https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000';
  // image = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0?fm=jpg';
  offset = 100;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      this.images.push({ defaultImage: "https://www.placecage.com/1000/1000", image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443890923422-7819ed4101c0?fm=jpg" });
    }
  }
}
```

and component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of images">
  <img [defaultImage]="i.defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="i.image" [offset]="offset">
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect if it move interface at end of the file this would work. I suspect app component not initialize with meta data because interface in bitween

Comment: thank you Amal Shalika.